# Изменение цвета ссылок при боковом скроле

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть `html` разметка, страница скролится по горизонтали, причем перелистывается не по странице а плавный скролл, меню остается статически и не скролится, проблема в том что страницы на которых фон белый, ссылок не видно...

Подскажите как решить проблему, пожалуйста, вот разметка скроллинга.

```html
<header class="white-color">
  <div class="container-fluid header-top">
    <div class="row border-row">
      <div class="col-xl-2 l left-section-top logos">
        <a href="#page1" class="logo-section" data-page="page1"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-7">
        <div class="top-menu">
          <a href="#2" data-page="page2">О компании</a>
          <a href="#3" data-page="page3">Клиенты</a>
          <a href="#4" data-page="page4">Услуги</a>
          <a href="#5" data-page="page6">Автопарк</a>

          <a href="#vacancy" data-page="page9">Вакансии</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-3">
        <div class="contacts">
          <a href="tel:+99999999" class="tel">+799999999</a>
          <a href="mailto:999999" class="eml">9999999</a>
        </div>
        <div id="burger">
          Меню
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</header>

<div id="makeMeScrollable">
  <div class="scrollWrapper kinetic-active">
    <article id="1" class="slider__item about page1">Верстка страницы 1</article>
    <article id="2" class="slider__item about page2">Верстка страницы 2</article>
    <article id="3" class="slider__item about page3">Верстка страницы 3</article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавить шрифту белый text-shadow ?)

Comment: Тогда text-shadow будет и на первом слайде, мне нужно что бы когда на ссылку заходит второй слайд ссылка меняла свой цвет

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно "слушать" скрол и на определенных брейкпоинтах, когда появляется белый фон у ссылок менять с помощью js цвет ссылок на контрастный.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  // тут пишешь условия срабатывания на определенном интервале
});
```

Соответственно ставишь определяешь второй брейкпоинт на котором цвет ссылок возвращается в обычное состояние.

Comment: var scrollPos = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var st = $(this).scrollLeft();
   if (st > scrollPos){
     $(".top-menu a").css("color", "red");
   } else {
     $(".top-menu a").css("color", "black");
   }
   scrollPos = st;
});
Сделал так и не работает

Comment: https://codepen.io/Fainor/pen/jOWrMgb
Смысл я думаю понятен. Тут подключен Jq